# How can I get a callback when UITableView has stopped scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my iPhone app, I have a bunch of code running in a single method. At the end of the method I have a few lines which need to be delayed so they only run after what goes before, this is because there is animating going on I need to run this code when the animation completes.

I know I could just use an NSTimer, but I was wanting to try something a little more elegant or cleaner.

Comment: What methods are you using to do animations? They might have a `completion:` block callback at the end you could use, which is definitely the appropriate way to handle it (instead of an extra timer).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, I am using the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method on UITableView and it doesn't have a block method available.

Comment: @JoshKahane You should ask a more specific question, e.g. _How can I get a callback when UITableView has stopped scrolling?_

Comment: I can see why that would help, sorry. I was trying to keep it as broad as possible so I or others can apply any answers to as many situations as possible. Thats all.

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, which has in its delegate the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`. Have you tried using that? Add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your tableview's delegate and see if it will fire that method.

Comment: -- As an alternate you can monitor for the `UIViewAnimationDidStopNotification`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for the first process  :

```
– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

this will block your thread until the process in done.

After this your next statement will start to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The standard (and very convenient) iOS way of doing this is callback blocks. Consider a simple UI animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
                   myView.alpha = 1; // fade-in myView
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // this code gets called when the animations block above is finished
                 }];
```

You can implement your own method that take a completion block as a parameter, and call it at the end of its execution. Here's the [Apple's block tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) that should get you started on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a delay even after the animation is over, you can call your second process with:

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]
```